# Kotlin/Spring Boot Application Fails to Build in Maven using Docker

Tags: docker, maven, kotlin, kotlin-maven-plugin

I am trying to build an image for Kotlin/Spring Boot application. But when I run `docker build` I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.7.20:compile (compile) on project download-common: Compilation failure
[ERROR] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find extension point configuration extensions/compiler.xml (cp:
[ERROR]   null)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.registerApplicationExtensionPointsAndExtensionsFrom(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:612)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createApplicationEnvironment(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:587)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.getOrCreateApplicationEnvironment(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:518)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.getOrCreateApplicationEnvironmentForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:499)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:443)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:192)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:143)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:53)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:99)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:47)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.KotlinCompileMojoBase.execCompiler(KotlinCompileMojoBase.java:228)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.K2JVMCompileMojo.execCompiler(K2JVMCompileMojo.java:237)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.K2JVMCompileMojo.execCompiler(K2JVMCompileMojo.java:55)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.KotlinCompileMojoBase.execute(KotlinCompileMojoBase.java:209)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.K2JVMCompileMojo.execute(K2JVMCompileMojo.java:222)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:370)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:351)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:171)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:163)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:294)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:960)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

The code compiles just fine when I run the same `mvn clean install -e` on my local machine without docker. After a bit of Googling, I added the below entry to plugins. The `requiresUnpack` section.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <requiresUnpack>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>kotlin-compiler</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </requiresUnpack>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

My Dockerfile is:

```
# AS <NAME> to name this stage as maven
FROM scratch
LABEL MAINTAINER="Sam"

#SETUP Ubuntu ENVIRONMENT
FROM ubuntu:latest as ubuntu

RUN export http_proxy=MY_PROXY_URL && export https_proxy=MY_PROXY_HTTPS_URL

#INSTALL JAVA
FROM eclipse-temurin:11-jdk-alpine AS jdk    

#INSTALL MAVEN
FROM maven:3.8.6-eclipse-temurin-11-alpine AS maven

COPY settings.xml /usr/share/maven/conf/

RUN apk update && apk add git && apk add net-tools procps openssh-client openssh-server

RUN mkdir -p $HOME/images/lib/ && cd $HOME/images/lib/

RUN git clone MY_GIT_URL

WORKDIR /download_code

RUN git checkout feature/docker-branch

RUN mvn clean install -e
```

It is a SpringBoot Application with Kotlin. And if its of any use, I am on Windows 10.

But I still get the same error. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: try `mvn clean package` only with docker not include `install`.

Comment: @life888888 Unfortunately I get the same with `mvn clean package -e` too

Comment: Why `docker build` would compile and package your kotlin project, can you put your `Dockerfile`? And you may want a `docker-maven-plugin`?

Comment: @Seven I have added my docker file to the main question.

Comment: you want to build a kotlin springboot app docker image or just want to use maven docker image  to build a kotlin springboot app jar ?

Comment: @life888888 Its the second one.

Comment: @life888888 Its the second one. I am trying to checkout the latest code from GIT, build it with maven and then run the spring jar from within the Dockerfile. That is the objective. But being new, I still learning as I go along!

Comment: It is recommended to divide things into two stages. The first stage is to generate jar files, and the second stage is to package jar files into docker images.Sorry English is not my native language so I use Google Translate, I hope you can understand, why my description is very short

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue with custom classloading mechanism implemented in Kotlin library.

Check these two links:

- [Kotlin forums](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-exception-on-kotlin-script-evaluation/6547)
- [Github](https://github.com/sdeleuze/kotlin-script-templating/issues/7)

The solution that worked for me:

```
tasks.named<BootJar>("bootJar") {
  requiresUnpack("**/kotlin-*.jar")
}
```

But this is gradle.
[Here's](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging.repackage-goal.parameter-details.requires-unpack) similar feature for maven:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <requiresUnpack>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-compiler-embeddable</artifactId>
      </dependency>
    </requiresUnpack>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

not sure if it works, maybe you will need to mark some more libraries.